# Move belongings from USA to Canada while temporarily staying in home country India?

Tags: working-visas, canada, usa

I don't have a Canadian visa just yet, so I'll first move to my home country of India for a month. I can't take my stuff to India and will have to rely on packers and movers to transport it from the US to Canada, once I get a Canadian work permit. 
My car also needs to move.

Will this work? What problems could arise?

Comment: I don't have a comprehensive answer to your question, so just a comment: Do not assume that it will be easy to import a car from the US to Canada. The motor vehicle regulations have important differences that can make importing a car expensive or even impossible. Do your research.

Comment: Thanks! I saw there are agents who do that and there are some forms that need to be in order. What could be a solution? Ship the car already to a friend living in Canada? Selling is a deal of loss.

Comment: Having a friend already living in Canada doesn't address the problem: the challenge is getting the Canadian authorities to accept the importation of a US-spec car. This is not a trivial matter. Read an introduction at https://www.riv.ca/ImportingAVehicle.aspx, the website of the private firm contracted by the Canadian government to do this work. While you may well lose money by selling the car in the US, doing so and then buying a Canadian vehicle would be *much* easier.

Comment: @David and for some models, it would even be cheaper.  I don't suppose that replacing a speedometer is possible for less than several hundred dollars.  10101010: in other words, it's not just the forms that must be in order but the car itself.  If significant mechanical work is required, you will be better off selling your car and buying a new one.

Comment: Thank you everyone for wonderful insights, I’ll keep in mind :))

Comment: I want to move a Hyundai Tucson 2013 from New York to Toronto, if that helps.

Comment: Drill down on the page I referenced, and you'll find that Hyundais built after 2007 for the US are indeed regulated by Canada, and may require modifications so the car can be permanently admitted into Canada.

Comment: I got the car into Canada without any modifications. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did this, and it worked. I put the car at my friend's and stored my boxes in a self storage. I found a company which was nice enough to head to the self storage, check out the items, and close my account. I got the car without issues.

Comment: Is the car merely now physically located in Canada, or is it actually licensed in Canada?